# Error while initializing birdirectional_dynamic_rnn with MultiRNNCell - shape mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get an error while initializing birdirectional_dynamic_rnn with MultiRNNCell - shape mismatch.

My code is :

```
def __init__(self, args):
    self.args = args
    self.input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, args.sentence_length, args.word_dim])
    self.output_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, args.sentence_length, args.class_size])
    with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
        fw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(args.rnn_size, state_is_tuple=True)
        fw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(fw_cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)
        #print("ff", fw_cell.get_shape())
        fw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([fw_cell] * args.num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
        #print("fw", fw_cell.get_shape())
    with tf.variable_scope('backward'):    
        bw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(args.rnn_size, state_is_tuple=True)
        bw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(bw_cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)
        bw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([bw_cell] * args.num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
    words_used_in_sent = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(self.input_data), reduction_indices=2))
    self.length = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(words_used_in_sent, reduction_indices=1), tf.int32)
    output, _= tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(fw_cell_1, bw_cell_1,
                                           self.input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
```

where `word_dim` is 311, `class_size` is 5, `rnn_size` is 256, `num_layers` is 2, sentence_length is 25

This is the error:

```
error is ValueError: Trying to share variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (512, 1024) and found shape (567, 1024).
```

Answer (score 0):

fw_cell and bw_cell ‘s rnn_size  must the same with input_data's word_dim
,but you word_dim is 311 and rnn_size is 256